# Is the image visible or not

Tags: javascript, dom, visibility

***Test if the image I am about to grab using code is visible to the user or not***

**Limitations**:

1. Plain javascript - please do not suggest jQuery or other framework
2. I am only interested in `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` but opacity and such is of course welcome

**Code:** below (taken from *[here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5757))* does not work in my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/RnpXG/)**

**Question:** Can you help making either work or suggest a better script?

*Version A*

```
function isVisible(obj){
  if (obj == document) return true;
  if (!obj) return false;
  if (!obj.parentNode) return false;
  if (obj.style) {
    if (obj.style.display == 'none' || obj.style.visibility == 'hidden') return false;
  }
  else if (window.getComputedStyle) { // MY BAD - I PUT THE INCORRECT ELSE HERE
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(obj, "");
    if (style.display == 'none' || style.visibility == 'hidden') return false;
  }
  else if (obj.currentStyle) {
    var style = obj.currentStyle;
    if (style['display'] == 'none' || style['visibility'] == 'hidden') return false;
  }
  return isVisible(obj.parentNode);
}
```

*Version B*

```
function isVisible1(obj) {
  var cnode = obj;
  try {
    while(cnode) {
      if (cnode.nodeName) {
        if (cnode.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="body") {
          return true;
        }
      }
      if (cnode.style.display=="none" || cnode.style.visibility=="hidden") {
        return false;
      }
      cnode = cnode.parentNode;
    }
    return true;
  }
  catch(ex) {return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the computed style conditionals outside the else of the style check. We want to check both the inline styles and the computed styles (from stylesheets.)

Changing:

```
else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
```

To:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXgbh/1/